# The best scenario for build process in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, solution

I have have several solutions in TFS Project. I want to synchronize all build numbers with each other for assignment work item in tfs 2010 client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share a single AssemblyInfo file between them all - so there is a single AssemblyVersion.

Create an AssemblyInfo.cs file, then in each project right-click on the project and select "Add Existing Item", browse to the shared AssemblyInfo and carefully click on the down-arrow on the "Add" button, so you can select "Add As Link".

Now drag the AssemblyInfo.cs file into the "Properties" folder of your project.

Repeat for each project. You can now double click on the shared AssemblyInfo.cs file in any of these projects and edit the version and it will apply to all.